# Pressing F5 in Visual Studio 2010 Builds but does not Launch Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a Click Once application (WPF) in C#.  Initially when I would hit F5 to debug/launch the application it worked smoothly.  Eventually, F5 only would build the solution and not launch the application (therefore I could not step through my code).  For a short while I switched from Debug to Release mode and for some reason that allowed the application to launch after using F5 and I could step through my code again.  But now that no longer works either.  Long story short, I cannot get the application to run in a manner that allows me to step through the code. I can only do a Start without Debugging (Ctrl + F5).  Obviously this doesn't do much for me other than tell me if the application works or not.

Comment: does the menu-commands for debuging work? Or the context-menue for that in the solution-explorer? A "clean"/"rebuilt" - reboot of your machine? If everything fails (and your app is indeed compiling, and the debug-settings in the project settings are correct) than maybe you have to reinstall VS...

Comment: Do you have more than 1 project in the solution?  If so, make sure you're launching the correct one.  Otherwise, post details of your project's Advanced Compile Settings and Debug project settings tab.

Comment: Look in Tools->Customize->KeyBoard. What's the value for Debug.Start command?

Comment: Do you get any info in the Output Window?

Comment: Which project is StartUp application in the solution.

Comment: oh my - just add a screenshot of your solution-window ....

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll answer a few of them quickly...  Overall no luck so far.  What specifically am I looking for under Solution|Properties?  Under the Services tab I do have the following error: An error occurred trying to load the page.
Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)).   I did forget(or it changed) to have a startup object.  I added my programName.app to this.  I will try rebooting the machine.  My Debut.start command is still F5.  The output windows shows the solution being successfully built, but then that's it.  Thanks for the tips so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have lost your start up project in the solution, or the start up project is messed up, and no correct "item" is defined for the startup.

Right click on one of your projects, and select : define as startup project. 
Then retry that should do the trick. If not, check in that projects properties to see if a form or something is defined as the startup object for that project.

Edit : Obviously dont define a class library project as startup project, but choose your UI :).

Comment: If the OP had designated a Library project he would have had a clear error message.

Comment: Yeah, but sometimes you have weird projects, like a winforms project that actually acts as business or something like that. And yes, I dont think he defined a Library as startup project. Rather he simply "deleted" the startup project, or messed it up in some way or another.

Comment: I was missing a startup object, but have added one and the problem persists.

Comment: Are you sure that your startup project has a startup item ?

Comment: Yes, I only have one project.  It is set as the start up project.  The project itself also has a startup object.   I do occassionally also get the following message:  "The operation cold not be completed.  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."  I don't get this message everytime, but usually need to exit/re-start visual studio 2010 to avoid getting it the next time I hit F5.

Comment: Interesting.  I went under the bin>Debug folder and deleted out every file there (except for the language folders).  I rebuilt the application under Debug and it started it up and allowed me to step through the code again!  It also allowed me to do the same under Release mode, although I hadn't done anything under the bin>Release folder.  Not sure if this is a coincidence with restarting the PC or not because I had tried debugging a few times after the restart and before deleting these files still with no luck.  I will continue to test this "theory" and post back with results.

Comment: So the manual "clean" worked ? Keep that in mind, happens from time to time

Answer (score 7):

The thing that worked for me today was to open Task Manager and look for any debug programs that didn't terminate properly.

```
Task Manager > Processes > kill all programs "*.vshost.exe *32"
```

Comment: Yup, worked for me as well.  Was your Visual Studio also extremely laggy when that happened?  Every know that then I'll have this problem and my Visual Studio becomes nearly unresponsive.

Comment: Yeah. And it seems to happen more often when I've left the computer on a few too many days, but by no means is "turn it off and on again" a part of the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help! And @NickMiller, VS was really laggy for me beforehand!

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue today and came here looking for help.  I tried all the suggestions here and nothing helped.

Seeing as my solution was a simple console application I recreated it from scratch.  The new solution didn't exhibit the problems, so I started comparing the two.

I reset the solution and project files so that they were identical (apart from Project GUID,  name and root namespace) but the first solution still didn't run.

I then tried deleting the suo files, and the bin and obj folders.  Still the first solution wouldn't run.

Finally, I noticed the vshost.exe process was still running for the project.  When I killed that and reloaded, it all started working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem today. The solution turned out to be a slight twist on the issue with *.vshost.exe mentioned previously.

I could build the application just fine but msvs refused to launch it. I could manually launch the application and the time stamp on the file indicated that it was in fact a fresh build as well. *.vshost.exe wasn't showing up in the task manager, so I couldn't end the process as suggested.

When all else failed, I tried deleting the .exe's and found that *.vshost.exe would not delete because it was in use. The error message indicated that it was actually the steam client (third party software) that had somehow grabbed my *.vshost.exe file and was "using" it. Not sure how or why. At any rate, I completely shut down steam, then it let me delete *.vshost.exe. After that, building and running from msvc worked normally.

Comment: Yea I would like to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, eventually tried deleting all breakpoints and the debug started working again. Yet to figure out why, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the ghost *.vshost.exe. It could also be that you have the same Solution/Project open in another version of VS. I had the same Solution open in both VS2010 and VS2015 and when running in VS2010 it compiled but failed to start. Closing the VS2015 Solution and it ran as expected.

Answer (score 0):

After years of using VS 2008, I suddenly had the F5 problem not launching the application.  There must be a dozen different suggestions out there - I tried a few.  Someone suggested a virus. My Microsoft Security Essentials was not automatically updating (a common problem it seems), so I manually updated it.  It found a virus, removed it, and the F5 problem went away !

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem and tried to delete everything in bin/debug folder but could not delete vshost.exe file - kept requesting admin permission and then still could not remove it even though running from admin account. Restarted and file was gone and f5 worked again