# Visual Studio C#/WPF 2010 xbap projects no longer debugging

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, debugging, xbap

I have scoured this site and others for similar issues, and have found some that are somewhat similar, but none of the fixes seem to work for me.

When starting a debug, it loads IE, and then immediately detaches from the process.  Interestingly enough, it also does not load the most recent version of the .xbap unless I clear the cache first.  Both of these behaviors did not start until after I published a test version to have some folks on my team try it out before deciding whether or not to continue.

I tried creating a brand new solution to determine whether or not something within my individual project settings were causing this to occur, but the problem follows to a new WPF Browser application project.  Standard C# Windows Form applications are still debugging as expected.

I've been tearing my hair out scouring forums trying to figure out what the issue is and what could have caused it to happen after simply publishing like I've done so many times before with other projects.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which IE version is being loaded, 32bit or 64bit?...which is your default Browser?...Is your application compiled for 32bit only (x86) 64bit only (x64), or AnyCPU? Is it a full-trust XBAP? or partial?....Try and debug via the method mentioned here. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/4dc15309-540e-434c-91b5-5b6f759319af/

Comment: loaded:32bit, default:32bit, compiled for AnyCPU.  Full trust XBAP (though also tried as partial)

Comment: Which OS are you using? If Windows 7, do you have SP1 installed? Which version of Framework are you using?

Comment: Check this link...it mentions problem with certificates....http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/05/23/whats-new-in-clickonce-deployment-in-net-4-0/ ... if not that, then turn on ClickOnce Logging...http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/enhanced-logging-in-clickonce-deployment/  ... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/32d84703-b11d-4b86-a149-c30c581b97db

Comment: Still does not work even when using PresentationHost.exe as the startup project for debugging.

Comment: XP Pro (I know), .NET 4.0.  The reason this is all baffling is that it worked without a hitch PRIOR to publishing.  Now it seems to have broken it even for new WPF web app projects.

Comment: Try uninstalling the app, then reinstall, instead of updating. .....and use the logging links mentioned above.

Comment: There are no errors, warnings, anything in the verbose log.  I have cleared the cache (apps\2.0, mage -cc, etc). It also now occurs with brand new solutions that have not been published/installed ever before, like file->new project->new wpf web application->press F5, debugger does not attach.

Comment: Maybe this will help....use the clickonce security settings and using the hosting process....http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/12/16/isolated-storage-windows-and-clickonce.aspx

Comment: Some final ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609486/pressing-f5-in-visual-studio-2010-builds-but-does-not-launch-application ... also try manually deleting the entire obj+bin directories by hand...not just a clean build

Comment: Already did those, deleted obj+bin about 4,000 times as well.